# Select Option Condition Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel

h-i  g,u,y,s
( haha i passed it )

i have 2 select option in my laravel view which show the data of 2 table in database

now i want to have a condition for these 2 select option

My First Select Option

```
<select>
<option>laptop</option>
<option>tablet</option>
</select>
```

if i select "Laptop" i want to show some data on my second select option and if i select "Tablet" i want show other data

in one more language:

> i want the options of a second select to be dynamic, based on the
>   selected option of the first select element.

what should i do?!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want the options of a second select to be dynamic, based on the selected option of the first select element.

To do this you need javascript.

So for example using jQuery you would do something like this.

```
<select id="select-device">
    <option value="laptop">Laptop</option>
    <option value="tablet">Tablet</option>
</select>

$(document).on('change', '#select-device', function( event ) {
    loadSelectedDeviceOptions($(this).val());
});

function loadSelectedDeviceOptions(selectedOption) {
    // You can either hide/show options or change the actual html of select B here
}
```